# Run pip through jenkins-plugin?

Tags: python, linux, jenkins, pip

If pip is not installed on the jenkins linux-box,
is there any jenkins-plugin that lets me run pip, without installing it at the os-level?

Comment: Why can't you install it? This sounds like an XY problem

Answer (score 0):

Create a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). It should come with pip, but otherwise install it in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Not a specific plug-in like you might want, but as was said, you can create a virtual environment in one of a few ways to get the functionality you're after.

Docker can handle this, you can create a small script to build a docker image that will have access to pip and there are Jenkins plug-ins for docker.